# How to transform individual instances with nested instancing from points

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a nested `Instances on points` setup, which I can basically break down into a `mesh line` instanced on another `Mesh line` and then some object instanced on the resulting points. I want to transform (ie rotate) each instance of the object individually but unfortunately the nestet instancing has the effect, that the objects in each column transform exactly the same.

Nodetree:
[image]

Result:
[image]

My real node setup is a way more complicated, so I cant just use a grid instead of nested mesh lines or a `Realize Instances` node for the first mesh line.

This is the actual nodetree:
[image]

1st Mesh line in my simplified example:
[image]

2nd Meshline:
[image]

Instancing:
[image]

The result is a fern-like plant:
[image]

I would like to rotate each individual leave (yellowish Leave Object Node), they are instanced on the 2nd Meshline.

And here is the blendfile just in case (the instance on point nodes are marked red for orientation):
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us the actual node tree, and not just an example where the use of `Realize Instances` would lead to the correct result.

Comment: Sure thing. :) added more screenshots and the blend file. I thought my simplified example would be enough as a solution without `Realize Instances` would apply to both.

Comment: OK, this is a bit more extensive than expected and I don't have time to go through it in detail at the moment, but are you sure that you are rotating the correct axis (currently Z)? ...Maybe try the Y axis. (Or I haven't quite understood the question yet. In that case, I would ask you to sketch the expected result).

Comment: yeah, no worries. I dont expect anyone to try to understand that nodetree in their freetime. The endshape is almost what I want to achieve already. I just wanted to add some variation in rotation and scale to the leaves, so it doesnt look so uniform. Stem and branches already have some random deformation and rotation (just to be clear: Stem -> Branch -> leaves).

Comment: Don't worry, I already understand the concept;-) ...but I'm not quite sure what the end result should look like (at least I can't see any obvious "mistake" in the nodes)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't enter a nested instance to modify instances inside. That is, you can't realize the outer instance, keeping the inner instances. But I think (It's late here, my brain doesn't quite work), you can capture instance properties like rotation, convert instances to points, and then duplicate the original of the outer instances (group of inner instances) as many times as points, adjust all the duplicated (inner) instances and then apply on them the outer transformation sampled by duplicate index from the points.